# Python: How to export an environment .yml file without OS specific libraries / for specific script?

Tags: python, conda, environment

I am working on a project in Python for Jupyter Notebook. I want to share my environment as a .yml file with my professor so he can reproduce what my script does. When i use Conda to export my environment like this: `conda env export --no-builds > my_environment.yml` i get an environment .yml file that includes all dependencies that my Python environment has without builds, like i initially wanted. Normally this would be fine, but since my professor is using macOS and i am using Windows i want to export an environment .yml file that does not include OS specific libraries. These OS specific libraries include:

`- winpty=0.4.3
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0
  - pywinpty=0.5.5
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0
  - powershell_shortcut=0.0.1
  - vc=14.1
  - wincertstore=0.2
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0
  - pyreadline=2.1
  - pywin32=223
  - vs2015_runtime=14.15.26706
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757
  - menuinst=1.4.16
  - icc_rt=2019.0.0
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0
  - win_unicode_console=0.5
  - comtypes=1.1.7`

Is there any easy way to export an environment .yml file that does not include these OS specific libraries and builds? Additionally, is there any easy way to export an environment .yml file that only include libraries that a specific script is dependent on?

I am very new to handling environments, so i hope there is a fairly straightforward answer to this out there... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you might be looking for [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms):

```
conda env export --from-history
```

which exports only the packages that you have installed specifically (i.e. called `conda install` with).

If there are packages that you have installed specifically that are OS dependent, then there is unfortunately no way to have an automatic way to exclude them from the yml file.